# Joomla Sessions and VirtueMart Cart - how to save cart information

Tags: php, session, cookies, joomla, virtuemart

I'm trying to extend the lifetime of the shopping cart for guest users up to a couple of days.
So that if a user comes back his shopping cart it filled again with the products he has prev. selected.

What I figured so far is:

The VirtueMart Cart stores it's cart-information in the field "data" in the table "_session".
When I extend the session-lifetime in joomla general settings, I can achieve that these entries are stored for let's say 5 days.

Now I believe that I only have to alter the VM-Objects to:

1. Check if cookie is already on user's mashine
2. read the session_id out of the cookie and find the session info in table "_session" then read information into shopping cart.

If no cookie present proceed as usual.

Now I don't know if this is something I have to change on joomla's session handling or something in the VM component.

Has anybody tried something like this before? Other solution ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the cart saving problem. With this plugin you could handle saved carts (alter / delete them from backend). 
www.awebsupport.com , and the backend version: http://awebsupport.com/virtuemart-cart-watching-system

Comment: Hey Alex. Please explain a bit more what this plugin does to solve that problem, and how it is to be used. The reason is your answer must be able to stand useful by itself. What if this link becomes dead in the future?